# What is the covariance between X and Y, when $Y>0$ if $X<0$ and $Y<0$ if $X>0$?

Tags: correlation, variance, random-variable, covariance, independence

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables, and $Y>0$ when $X<0$ and $Y<0$ when $X>0$, but can we conclude Cov$(X,Y)<0$?

If the question only states $Y>0$ when $X<0$, then the statement Cov$(X,Y)<0$ is certainly not true. But what if $X$ takes on both positive and negative values?

Comment: What have you done to work this out yourself? - just saying because this looks like homework/self study

Comment: I've put my thoughts in the question already. I can do no more. It was an interview question.

Comment: Can you say anything about $E (XY)$ ? What about $E(X)E (Y) $?

Comment: @probabilityislogic $E[XY] < 0$, but nothing can be said about $E[X]E[Y]$ because we don't know the signs on $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$, right?